# Mocking config for unit testing a grails controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails

In grails 1.3.7, I access some external properties via the ConfigurationHolder in my controller.  Googling around suggests I can use the following in the setup of my unit test:

```
    mockConfig '''
        sys.admin.username = "username"
        sys.admin.password = "password"
    '''
```

when my unit tests run ConfigruationHolder.config is null.  So more googling lead me to try this in the setup:

```
    def mockedConfig = new ConfigObject()
    mockedConfig.sys.admin.username = "username"
    mockedConfig.sys.admin.password = "password"
    ConfigurationHolder.config = mockedConfig
```

still getting a null config object in the unit test.  I also tried the hiearctical syntax for this first style and it didn't work either:

```
    mockConfig('''
        sys { admin {
            username = 'username'
            password = 'password'
        } }
    ''')
```

I am new to grails so I am stumbling my way through this and would like to get my controller unit tested.  How do I get around a null config object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, it was a timing issue.  I held a reference to the configurationholder in my controller class:

```
def config = ConfigurationHolder.config
```

Moving that inside the method where it was needed worked.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Thank you for remotely helping me out. 
Did you understood well the issue ? I did not. If you could explain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH

....


def username = CH.config.sys.admin.username
def password = CH.config.sys.admin.password
```